# How to keep index of Array of objects when using Array.filter() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

This is a screenshot of a simple todo list that is supposed to keep the items todo on the left and move the completed items to the box on the right: https://prnt.sc/dO_YFfgWAkC8

The problem is when I use Array.filter() to sort the items into a new Array based on their completed status, they don't maintain their index. This causes the item I check off to move correctly to the box on the right but then applies a checkmark to an item with the same index in the new array.

Query from GraphQL:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(TODOS_QUERY);
```

Data:

```
data.todos = [ 
  {
    "id":"1",
    "title":"1",
    "completed":true
 },
 {
    "id":"2",
    "title":"2",
    "completed":false
 },
 {
    "id":"3",
    "title":"3",
    "completed":true
 }
]
```

toggleComplete function:

```
const toggleCompleted = (id) => {
  toggle({variables: { id }});
  reset();
}
```

Box on the left:

```
{data.todos
  .filter(item => item.completed === false)
  .map((todo, key) => (
    <li onChange={() => toggleCompleted(todo.id)}
    key={key}><FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label={todo.title} /></li>
))}
```

Box on the right:

```
{data.todos
    .filter((item) => item.completed === true)
    .map((todo, key) => (
      <li className="completed-item" onChange={() => toggleCompleted(todo.id)}
      key={key}><FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label={todo.title} /></li>
))}
```

How do I maintain the index in my specific example? If I refresh the page it fixes itself but how do I do it the React way by updating the state or just maintaining the same index in the new Array that is created? I do already refetch the query to update the state when I click the checkbox but that moves the checkbox to the right and doesn't solve the issue of the next checkbox on the left box with the same index being checked.

Comment: This is why indexes shouldn't be used as keys. You have I'd property, use it instead

Comment: Try changing `key={key}` to `key={todo.id}` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was passing a key through the map method like this:

```
map((item, key) => (
   <li key={key}>My items...</li>
))
```

The solution was to remove the key from map and just use the id of the item:

```
map(item => (
   <li key={item.id}>My items...</li>
))
```

If you are following react tutorials when they do this, don't make a bad habit of it. This error threw me through a loop and is a really simple concept once you understand it.